# Query AccountID of a pallet

Tags: polkadot-js, pallet, accountid

The AccountID of a pallet is generated using the PalletID. (See the example from [Treasury pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L513))

I know is possible to query this pallet ID because is a constant, but my question is:

Is there a way to query the AccountID of a pallet using PolkadotJS app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be "queried", but it can be generated using the queried Pallet ID.

You can see an example of that here: https://github.com/shawntabrizi/substrate-js-utilities/blob/master/utilities.js#L218

For example using: https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/

You will get:

`py/trsry` -> `5EYCAe5ijiYfyeZ2JJCGq56LmPyNRAKzpG4QkoQkkQNB5e6Z`

https://polkadot.subscan.io/account/5EYCAe5ijiYfyeZ2JJCGq56LmPyNRAKzpG4QkoQkkQNB5e6Z