# Ensure that a call is dispatched from a specific pallet

Tags: pallet, frame, origin

So I want my instance of the pallet membership to be managed only by a specific pallet, and not even the Root origin.

Is there anyway to create an EnsureOrigin object that can verify that a specific pallet dispatched the call ?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the address of your pallet, and then easily compare with the origin address.

Check how to obtain the pallet address here [Query AccountID of a pallet](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6510/query-accountid-of-a-pallet), here [How can we get a Pallet's Sub-Account Address using PolkadotJS API](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/477/how-can-we-get-a-pallets-sub-account-address-using-polkadotjs-api) and here [How do i find the address of the treasury?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/how-do-i-find-the-address-of-the-treasury)